# Why does this C++ loop not run infinitely?

Tags: c++

I was watching my friend try to solve a programming challenge and at one point, his code looked like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std; 

int main(){ 
//Prompt user to enter string
const string SPACE {" "}; 
string input;

cout << "Please enter String you would like to see in a pyramid: "; 
getline(cin, input);

//Iterate string
for(int i {0}; i < input.length(); i++){ //Going through each character in string...
    for(int j {0}; j <= i; j++){ //Going through each character in string from 0 to i...
        cout << input[j];
    }
    for (int k {i}; k < input.length(); k--){ //Going backwards from string.length() to 0
        cout << input[k - 1];
    }
    cout << endl;
    }
}
```

The question I have is, why does the third for loop (last loop) not result in an infinite loop? k = 0 as the initial condition for the first iteration (since i = 0), and k is decremented by 1 for each iteration. Since the terminating condition should theoretically ALWAYS be false (k should always be less than input.length() for a positive integer length string), why does this loop terminate?

Comment: Even if this *does* work, I'm 90% sure it's undefined behavior. Tell your friend his code might fail at any moment.

Comment: Good point! I incorrectly assumed that it would actually result in a segfault.. I wonder why it doesn’t do that instead? Seems like a segfault situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note the comparison `k < input.length()`, where the `input.length()` returns **unsigned** `string::size`. If the `k` is negative, then the `int` will be converted and so its negative value will instead become a positive value.
If the `k` was -1 at that time, then this value will be the **biggest value possible** for the `string::size`. Try to print out the values and see for yourself.

For example:

```
int main () {
    int i = -1;
    size_t s = 10;
    std::cout << (i > s) << std::endl;
}
// Prints 1, which means the (i > s) is true
```

Answer (score 3):

`input.length()` returns an unsigned value (`size_t`). This results in `k` being promoted (converted) to an unsigned value, and then comparison is made.

When `k` is -1, it will be promoted to an Very Large Positive Number, which will not be less than the string length.

However, even before this happens, you access `input[-1]`, which results in undefined behavior (possibilities include a crash, display of a garbage value, or the program appearing to work properly).

Comment: Thank you very much! Just as a follow-up, why is the conversion done from int to an unsigned value for the purposes of the comparison? Why not convert the size_t to a signed value instead?

Comment: @Kevin Because that's the way the language is defined to behave.

Comment: Makes sense, although it is curious to me that they don’t define it the other way around since it would seemingly avoid surprising results like these.

Comment: @Kevin you would otherwise have had the surprise of a large size becoming a negative value. ;)

Comment: Good point! I suppose surprises like these are just an unavoidable part of the fun :)